# Paypal controlled with client id at run time

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

I'm implementing a iOS solution where I would like to setup Paypal Mobile SDK with client id provided dynamically based on user's selection.

Example:
Product A: Merchant M1
Product B: Merchant M2

If user purchases Product A, the payment should be made to Paypal client Id of Merchant 1.
If user purchases Product B, the payment should be made to Paypal client Id of Merchant 2.

Is there a possibility of changing this once the PayPalMobile is initialized?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the PayPal mobile SDKs are not designed to work in the way you describe.